# What is the symbol for faith?

Tags: meaning

I would like to get faith in Japanese for a tattoo. This is what I’ve seen. “信” and “信頼“ What is the difference between the two?

Comment: There is not a one-to-one correspondence between Japanese and English words. What exactly do you mean by 'faith' and what sentiment do you intend it to convey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that "信" has the meaning of trust or believing in something, for example:

> 妖精を信じてるのか。
> Do you believe in fairies?

Whereas "信頼" is the word I would use for a more "serious" kind of trust, for example:

> 私は医者を完全に信頼している。
> I have complete trust in my doctor.

If you want the term "faith" in a religious sense for your tattoo I would look into "信仰" instead. Another example:

> 母はキリスト教を信仰している。
> My mother believes in Christianity.

I took all of these examples from [Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BF%A1%E4%BB%B0), a place I would recommend you consult before getting your tattoo!

Answer (score 1):

信 or 信頼 is not come to my mind as a translation of faith.
Probably , Japanese does not have the perfect matching word with the faith.

信:Trust , Belief,  truth ,signal ,message  ,etc. (multi meaning word)
信頼:Trust